# Ubuntu preseed install. 50% of / and /tmp

Tags: ubuntu, installation, partitioning

I need to install ubuntu server 10.04 by preseed file and part disk into 50% for / and rest for /tmp. I tried this:

```
    # Partitioning
# use first hard drive SCSI/SATA:
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

# Actualy use 50% for / and rest 50% for /LOGS
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              2048 50% 1000000000 ext4                        \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              2048 50% -1 ext4                                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /TMP}                       \
              .                                               \
              50% 4096 50% linux-swap                         \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

Can anyone tell me, why it doesn't works? It creates only 1.9 Gb to / and /tmp.

Thanks!

Comment: Should be moved to http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Rather, Server Fault. This question is equally as applicable to Debian as Ubuntu — would be unfair to move it to an Ubuntu–only forum.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I solve that problem. I should use digital values instead of percentage.

```
# Partitioning
# use first hard drive SCSI/SATA:
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

# Actualy use 50% for / and rest 50% for /TMP
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              2048 30720 1000000000 ext4                      \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              50% 4096 50% linux-swap                         \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .                                               \
              2048 30720 -1 ext4                              \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /TMP }                      \
              .                                               \

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```